# Event horizon of static black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, event-horizon

I am interested in finding event horizon of static space times of the following forms :
\begin{equation}
ds^2=-f(r)dt^2+\frac{1}{g(r)}dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2,
\end{equation}
where we have $f(r)\neq g(r)$. According to the Carroll's book :

> 1-determinig the point at which r=constant hypersurfaces become null is easy; $\partial_{\mu}r$ is a one form normal to such hypersurfaces, with norm
> \begin{equation}
> g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}r\partial_{\nu}r=g^{rr},
> \end{equation}
> we are looking for the place where the norm of our one vanishes
> \begin{equation}
> g^{rr}(r_H)=0,
> \end{equation}

so from this definition, $g(r_H)=0$ is the location of event horizon.

2-But $K^{\mu}=\delta^{\mu0}$ is a time like Killing vector which becomes null $g_{\mu\nu}K^{\mu}K^{\nu}=g_{tt}(r_{H'})=0$ for some hypersurface which is located at $r=r_{H'}$.

It seems to me that 1&2 are contradictory according to Carroll's book which claims

> A-Every event horizon $\Sigma$ in a stationary, asymptotically flat space time is a Killing horizon for some Killing vector field $\xi^{\mu}$.

> B-If the space time is static, $\xi^{\mu}$ will be the Killing vector field $\partial_t^{\mu}$ representing time translations at infinity.

if $f(r_{H'})\neq g(r_H)$, the above conditions are not satisfied.

3-By looking at the null geodesics
\begin{equation}
\frac{dr}{dt}=\sqrt{f(r)g(r)},
\end{equation}
it seems to me that the event horizon should be the outer radios for which one of the functions $f(r)$ or $g(r)$ is equal to zero.

which one is the definition of event horizon? I am interested in an explicit calculation and not the general explanations as event horizon is the hypersurface for which spacetime is divided to two separately causally disconnected regions.

I found some answers to the similar questions without explicit calculations :

[How to derive the Schwarzschild radius?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190932/how-to-derive-the-schwarzschild-radius/190940#190940)

[What is the radius of the event horizon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191013/what-is-the-radius-of-the-event-horizon)

[Does condition $g_{00}(r_0)=0$ define the event horizon on $r_0$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759098/does-condition-g-00r-0-0-define-the-event-horizon-on-r-0)

Comment: In any case i have encountered $g(r)$ will eventually end up being something like $f(r)*h(r)$ with $h(r)$ being an analytic non zero function everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you use arbitrary metrics and coordinates the event horizon is at the contravariant $g^{\rm rr}=0$. In static Schwarzschild spacetime this gives the same result as the covariant $g_{\rm tt}=0$, otherwise the latter gives the static limit which can also happen at the ergosphere if there is one.